# Filling DataSet in Form Constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, data-binding, .net-4.5

By default, Visual Studio places the `TableAdapter.Fill()` method into `Form_Load()`.

On a secondary form, I'm considering moving the `Fill()` statement to the form constructor (after `InitializeComponent()` of course).  The intention is to handle any data loading issues sooner.

In my initial testing, this appears to work just fine.

Are there any potential issues introduced by filling a `DataSet` from the form constructor (ie: binding, event handling, etc)?

Comment: That's what I usually do and I never had problems with my bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance?

Depending on your design, Leaving it on the Load event method guarantees that the user has opened the form, you may have several forms that you might instantiate on another part of the project that user may or may not want to see, that would freeze the screen on heavy datasets.